# Does mypy check Never type at all?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I was playing with `Never` type in mypy. If I have a function `foo(x: int)` I expected that when called with a value of type `Never` mypy would complain, but it silently typechecks the call:

```py
from typing import Never


def foo(x: int):
    pass


def bar(x: Never):
    foo(x)  # ok, I exected a type error
    foo("foo")  # err
```

--- edit ---

Just for reference my solution to create a uninhabited type is this

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod, final

@final
class Never(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self) -> None: ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. `Never` is a subtype of every other type. After all, `Never` is the type with no values. All values of `Never` type are values of every other type, because there *are* no values of `Never` type.

Comment: Sort of like, "If 1 +1 = 3, then Santa Clause exists."  In that case, what's the difference between `typing.Never` and `typing.Any`?

Comment: @DanielWalker: Well, you can't `return 3` from a function annotated as `-> typing.Never`, while you could with `typing.Any`.

Comment: But as a function argument ...

Comment: @DanielWalker: Both `Never` and `Any` are compatible with any function parameter, no matter how that parameter was annotated. (On the other hand, a parameter *annotated as* `Any` accepts anything, while a parameter annotated as `Never` does not.)

Comment: Ahhhh, gotcha!  Makes sense.

Comment: "Never is the subtype of every other type", so now the uninhabited type is inhabited by all terms. Really? Damn subtyping

Comment: @geckos: I think you might be thinking of `Any` as the top type, and expecting the bottom type `Never` to behave the opposite of `Any`. `Any` isn't the top type - the top type is `object`, which indeed behaves the opposite of `Never`. `Any` is its own weird thing.

Comment: Oh, so is not the every value is a subtype of Never, is that, is that, assuming that a value of Never type exists this value is a subtype of all other types at the same time? This is okay because Never has no construtor